# Cambiar el formato de la fecha que recibo de YYYY-MM-DD a DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: php, date

Soy novato ,tengo la siguiente fecha: **2010-04-19**.
Quisiera convertir esta fecha al formato *DD-MM-YYYY*

Ejemplo, mi código.

```
// "fecha" => $this->input->post(date("d/m/Y", strtotime('fecha'));

$usuario = array(
    "nombre" => $this->input->post('nombre'),
    "fecha" => $this->input->post('fecha') /YYYY-MM-DD
);
```

Answer (score 18):

Para realizar el cambio podrías usar `strtotime()` y `date()` por ejemplo:

```
$originalDate = "2017-03-08";
$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

obtendrás en `$newDate` 08/03/2017

Si quieres colocar esa fecha en un arreglo puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$usuario = array(
                "nombre" => $this->input->post('nombre'),
                "fecha" => $newDate
           );
```

Ya que tienes almacenada la fecha en la variable `$newDate`

Comment: Si pero array debe obtendra en date?

Comment: No entendí tu comentario, que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: cómo ajustar un formato de fecha en una matriz

Comment: osea "dob" => date('d-m-Y',strtotime($this->input->post('dob')))

Comment: acabo de hacer editar la respuesta @DiegoSagredo

Comment: pero falta post , $originalDate = "fecha";  para insertar?

Comment: Por lo visto usas codeigniter, si traes tu fecha a través de `$this->input->post()` solo hace falta que llames a tu campo a traves de post `$this->input->post("fecha")` suponiendo que tu campo se llama fecha.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55015/discussion-between-diego-sagredo-and-juan-pinzon).

Comment: asi, $originalDate = $this->input->post('fecha');

Answer (score 4):

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data["fechai"]));
```

Este fue el que me sirvió a mí para pasar de `d-m-Y` a `Y-m-d` y así insertar en campo `Date` en SQL.

Comment: Para empezar, el autor de la pregunta está pidiendo obtener el formato opuesto. Sin embargo, no veo ninguna diferencia con las respuestas ya publicadas hace casi un año... ¿Qué aporta esta respuesta que no aporten otras?

Answer (score 3):

Antes de pasar los elementos del formulario por Post en tu js declara este código:

```
  $("#fecha" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
```

esto va a cambiar el formato de tu fecha de YYYY-MM-DD a DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: setDatePicker = function (element, options) {
    if (!options) {
        options = {};
    }
    var settings = $.extend({}, {
        autoclose: true,
        language: "custom",
        todayHighlight: true,
        weekStart: AppHelper.settings.firstDayOfWeek,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    }, options);

    $(element).datepicker(settings);
};

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

mas info en la pagina oficial de php
http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 2):

Si la fecha las estás enviando desde un `datepicker` sería lo siguiente

```
$(document).ready(function () {                    
    $('#fecha').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        clearBtn: true,
        language: "es",
        autoclose: true,
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        todayHighlight: true
    });              
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recibirla en el archivo php y darle formato así

```
$Nueva = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['fecha']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma seria usar la clase [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) con [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2017-02-01');
$fecha_d_m_y = $fecha->format('d/m/Y');

echo $fecha_d_m_y; // 01/02/2017
```

[Ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48deeda7bd0852d88db7bdf9bf4b85ad96733559)